# Issue with writeVideo/ VideoWriter MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, opencv, video-processing

I'm a beginner so sorry in advance for the mistakes.

I have a set of data from a camera recording saved in a 4D array with these dimensions (250x300x10603x12).
The first is the dimensions of the video (pixels). The 10603 are the FrameRatexTime. 12 are the subjects I recorded.

I extract one subject at a time for analysis in this way:

```
subj1 = data(:,:,:,1);
```

This brings me to an array containing the frames of subject 1, which I can display with implay.
Now I would like to write a video of this new array and save it in .avi format, I use this code:

```
v = VideoWriter('subj1.avi')
open(v)
writeVideo(v,subj1)
close(v)
```

but it keeps giving me this error

> Error using VideoWriter/writeVideo (line 410) IMG must be an array of
> either grayscale or RGB images.

In fact, looking at the shape of the array, there is nothing that points to a grayscale or RGB index. How can I get a .avi file in this case? Do I have to transform the array?
Why does it still display the video with implay?

*clarification: the fact that I have to transform the array into an .avi file is because I will have to analyse it by exporting it to Python with OpenCv.
In fact, if I export the .mat file directly to Python, I can't get the list of Frames.*

Answer (score 0):

Matlab's documentation for writeVideo says that for a sequence of grayscale images like you have, it is expecting a "height-by-width-by-1-by-frames" array. You are only passing it "height-by-width-by-frames".

So, you need to reshape your `subj1`. Maybe try doing it like this:

```
newsubj = zeros(250, 300, 1, 10603)
newsubj(:,:,1,:) = subj1
```

and then save `newsubj` instead of `subj1`:

```
writeVideo(v,newsubj)
```

Finally, I think you may get some lossy compression when you save as an `avi`, so it may not be the best way to export it from Matlab and importing it to Python.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer! I've tried your method but the result is this error: " Error using VideoWriter/writeVideo (line 410)
Requested 250x300x3x10603 (17.8GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays greater than this limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array size limit or preference panel for more information". How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: The fact that I have to export the file in .avi is because I'm using OpenCV in python and I'm not able to collect the frames in a Numpy Array that openCv can elaborate. Frames should be stored in a list of Numpy Array (because with openCv I use a for cycle where I read every frame. But instead, when I import it to Python using scipy.io they are stored as an Array of unit8 (dimension 250x300x10603). In what kind of way I can have this Frames saved in a list of Numpy Array?

Comment: Why is it 250x300x3x10603 rather than 250x300x1x10603? Is it an RGB image? It looks like you're running out of memory - this is a different problem to what you had before.  You're going to create a smaller `newsubj` array, say, 250x300x1x100, put only a part of `sub1` in, and write that to your avi. You could put it in a for loop and iterate through all the ranges you need.

Comment: I think it is an RGB image but I don't understand why. I tried to divide the array into smaller parts as you suggested but it doesn't work :( But I was thinking, doing something like that? 
`video = VideoWriter('subj1.avi') 
 N = length(newsubj)
 open(video) 
for ii = 1:N 
frame = newsubj(ii) 
writeVideo(video,frame)
end 
close(video)`
It creates a 1x10603 struct composed of 1x1x3 uint8. Implay is working BUT the video is totally black (without any image) so I'm missing something. Am I close or using a for cycle is incorrect?